# Remove crop on top background-image

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to figure out how I can remove the cropping on my background-image. Basically the bottom part is ok but the top is being cropped which I have no idea why. Here is an image of my problem!

[image]

As you can see the rounded border at the bottom can be seen but the top is basically hidden. I have tried using position:absolute, background-size:contain, position:relative with z-index or overflow:visible

Here is the code regarding my work.

**HTML**

```
<header class="">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="logo">
            <h1><a href="#">Maru Consulting</a></h1>
        </div>

        <nav class="">
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'main-menu' ) ); ?>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
}

html,body{
    height:100%; 
    background-image:url('images/maru-bg.jpg'); 
    background-position:center;
}

header{
    background-color:#850707; 
    width:100%; 
    height:40px; 
    margin-top:20px;
}

h1{float:left; margin-right:20px;}

h1 a{
    display:inline-block; 
    text-decoration:none; 
    background-image:url('images/maru-logo.png'); 
    width:306px; 
    height:59px; 
    text-indent:-99999px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:0 -10px;
    background-size:contain;
} 

nav{float:left;}

nav ul li a{text-decoration:none; color:#fff;}
```

Updated image

[image]

Comment: Where is the CSS for logo and container classes?

Comment: updated. There is no styling for the logo class. As you can see I just use "h1" and "a" for styling

Comment: Replace the background-position:0 -10px from h1 a withbackground-position: 0; and try

Comment: Also, what is the size of the logo?

Comment: Regarding the background position, the reason I added -10px is so that the rounded border of the top part of the logo can be seen but like I said it is cropped even though the rounded border of the bottom part of the logo can be seen. If set it back to 0px it will be return to its original position. The dimensions for the logo is 306 x 59

Comment: Try changing the height of header element to 59px

Comment: If you're using chrome make sure you using an incognito tab, extensions can sometimes mess with markup, for example last pass often adds a div at the top of the page.

Comment: Have you tried your code in another browser ? Are you facing the same issue ?

Comment: Yes, the problem is also the same in other browsers